# Getting thread errors when calling obtainPermanentIDsForObjects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I'm creating a new NSManagedObject and inserting it into a context with concurrency type private queue (so it runs on a background thread).

Right before I save, I call this:

```
[appDelegate.backgroundMOC obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:
       [NSArray arrayWithObject:newObject] error:&error];
```

Then I save:

```
[appDelegate.backgroundMOC save:&err];
```

However, I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash. Looking at the stacktrace, I see:

```
0 semaphore_wait_trap
7-[NSManagedObjectContentSave:]
```

I'm guessing the problematic line is the `semaphore_wait_trap`, but I'm not sure how that's caused.

**If I comment out the line `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects`, the problem goes away.**

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any other new managed objects that are "children" of the object you're getting the objectID for? If so, you need to add those objects to the array. It is a bug in core data.

Comment: No I don't think I deal with children and parent objects..

Comment: Were any other objects created and set as properties on newObject (other than core data primitives)?

Comment: You mean relationships? Yes I did assign some relationships, though not always creating those new objects, but fetching them, then assigning them..

Comment: Any new objects that were created should get passed to -obtainPermanentIDsForObjects: due to a bug that has been reported.

Comment: If I do `[backgroundMOC obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:
       backgroundMOC.managedObjects.allObjects error:&error];`, the problem goes away. Maybe this has something to do with what you're talking about?

Comment: How do you know this is a bug? Do you have a link?

Comment: Here's the open radar link: http://openradar.appspot.com/11478919

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to a bug in obtaining object ids (http://openradar.appspot.com/11478919), you need to pass in all newly created objects to `-[NSManagedObjectContext obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error:]`.